# How to use fastapi-users with google oauth (from official docs full example)

Tags: python, google-oauth, fastapi, fastapiusers

I've copied the [full sqlalchemy example from the fastapi-users docs](https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/11.0/configuration/oauth/#sqlalchemy_1) with `postgresql+asyncpg` and I have something working, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly with Google.

In the swagger UI I am able to use the Authorize form successfully and I can see fastapi reports `"POST /auth/jwt/login HTTP/1.1" 200 OK`.

I am trying to understand the order of endpoints being used in this authorization process. So in parallel I am using the swagger UI to execute the following steps:

1. Post to `/auth/jwt/login`. This returns `{"access_token": <some_token>, "token_type": "bearer"}`.
2. Post to `/auth/request-verify-token` and although in swagger the response body is `null`, the fastapi logs show `Verification requested for user 8d1c6256-c988-446d-b726-77ba934ceb5b. Verification token: <some_token>` followed by `"POST /auth/request-verify-token HTTP/1.1" 202 Accepted`.
3. Post to `/auth/verify` with the token from step 2, which returns `"POST /auth/verify HTTP/1.1" 200 OK` and the user info.

Is this the correct order of events? At what point does google come into play? I do not see any google endpoints being hit (`/auth/google/authorize` and `/auth/google/callback`). If I want to use google, do I need to modify the prefix in `get_auth_router()` or do I need to modify the full example in any way?

```
app.include_router(
    fastapi_users.get_auth_router(auth_backend), prefix="/auth/jwt", tags=["auth"]
)
```

Also, why are there 2 tables in the DB (`user` and `oauth_account`). I can see my google user in `user` but the `oauth_account` table is empty. Should both tables have been filled out?